# errorbars in pgfplots using raw gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I use pgfplots always in combination with the 'raw gnuplot' option because I like it better to preprocess my data using gnuplot. (curve fitting, complex calculations etc.)

Now I am facing a problem since I try to add errorbars to my plot, still using the 'raw gnuplot' option. I checked the manual and searched the internet for a solution, all I found was a workaround that isn't really satisfying:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape --synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode]

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
#x y x_err y_err
1 2 0.5 0.5
2 8 0.3 0.3
3 9 0.7 0.3
4 1 0.5 0.5
5 2 0.5 0.9
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

        \addplot gnuplot [
        draw=none,
        mark=none,
        forget plot,
        raw gnuplot,
        ] {
            plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with xyerrorbars;
        };
        \addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir=both,y explicit,
            x dir=both,x explicit,
        ] table [
            x error expr=((\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{2})/2),
            y error expr=((\thisrowno{5}-\thisrowno{4})/2),
        ]{\jobname.pgf-plot.table};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Anyone can help me with a solution, that can add errorbars while using 'raw gnuplot' and doesn't need the second 'addplot table'?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. PGFPlots will only look for the first two columns and process these when option `gnuplot` (and its friends) is(/are) used. As Christian told me, this will not be changed (in the near and mid future). Said this I think you already have the optimal solution ... Hopefully you will agree that I will vote to close this question as "unsolvable".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there is no possibility to solve the problem in the way OP is requesting it. (This will also not change in the near and mid future.)